# Is there a way for child pages inheriting their parent's index.vue file in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

So I've been trying to optimize my Nuxt.js application. And I've been struggling with one thing in particular that I'm finding hard to solve.

As you know, in Nuxt you have a `pages/` folder in which you define folders and `index.vue` files inside of those folders. This automatically gets translated into routes on the Frontend.

I have a `pages/_page` folder which catches all the `<website_url>/_page` routes. This `_page`'s `index.vue` file has a template which fetches content, etc. Now, in order for `<website_url>/_page/_subpage` to work I have to make **another** folder inside of the `_page` folder called `_subpage` with an `index.vue` and for `_subsubpage` it's the same story.

This will cause the folder structure to be as follows:
[image]

Now, the `index.vue` in _page, `_subpage` **and** `_subsubpage` are exactly the same. I need to do this because otherwise if I go to `<website_url>/_page/_subpage` without there being a `_subpage` folder and an `index.vue` file, Nuxt throws an error.

Is there a possibility to have `_subpage` inherit the index.vue from `_page` instead of having to make a folder and index.vue with the exact same content?

Thanks for reading/helping! If anything is unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the content in the main parent `index.vue` page inside of a component and use it in all the subpages.

Comment: Yea I've thought of doing that, but that doesn't really solve anything and only makes it more complex by adding more files. That's what I'm trying to avoid in this case. Thanks for the answer though.